# Font size of \url in footnote

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, urls

I use this `\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\normalsize}` for make the fontsize smaller. I will like to make somthing similar for making only the `\url` smaller and only when it is used in a footnote. Text in `\url` when it is placed in a footnote need to have the same fontsize as the the rest of the footnote.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  urlcolor=Blue}

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{WWW: \url{http://www.google.com/}}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{Homepage: \url{Homepage}}  Text Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text Text \url{Text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear; do you want to change the font size of URL's only or that of footnotes, including any URL they may contain? Please clarify.

Comment: Use the line `\expandafter\renewcommand\csname @makefntext\endcsname[1]{\makefootmark\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\footnotesize} #1}`

Comment: Thx, @MarcoDaniel you solution works perfectly.

Comment: @Jubobs, I tried to make it more clear now. MacrcoDaniel understod the question correctly

Comment: Why do you feel the need to set `\UrlFont` in the first place?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalsize}` does *not* make the font size smaller:

- Normal text has normal size: `\normalsize`. Thus you get the *same* size.
- `\normalsize` is a fixed size, thus the size does not adopt to different environments such as footnotes.
- It removes `\ttfamily`, thus you get the same font as in the context.

### Same font

If you want to have the same font for the URLs as the text before, then it can be set by `\urlstyle{same}`:

```
\documentclass[a6paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  urlcolor=Blue}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{WWW: \url{http://www.google.com/}}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{Homepage: \url{Homepage}}  Text Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text Text \url{Text}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result "same"]

### Smaller URL font size

If you only want to have smaller font sizes for URLs, then package `relsize` helps. `\relsize{-1}` or `\smaller\relax` can be used (the `\relax` prevents `\smaller` from searching for its optional argument in the next input tokens).

```
\documentclass[a6paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  urlcolor=Blue}

\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\smaller\relax}

\begin{document}

Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{WWW: \url{http://www.google.com/}}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{Homepage: \url{Homepage}}  Text
Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text
Text Text Text Text Text \url{Text}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result "smaller"]